# Какие бывают циклические проверки исключений?

Tags: java, циклы, исключения, try-catch

Нужно чтобы пользователь вводил переменную, пока он не введет ее правильно. Пока придумал только такой способ:

```
boolean check = true;

        do {
            try {
                cellNumber = input.nextInt();
                check = false;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }while (check);
```

Есть способ покрасивее?

Comment: Мм, пример искусственный? Потому что если `input` - это `Scanner`, то выброс исключения в методе `nextLine`, по-моему, будет говорить о том, что от scanner-а ничего толкового уже дождаться

Comment: @Regent да, забыл написать, что это Scanner. Второе предложение не понял, почему от Scanner не дождаться?

Comment: Метод [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) кидает два исключения: `NoSuchElementException` и `IllegalStateException`. Как добиться первого при вводе из консоли - не знаю, а второе случается при закрытом scanner-е (соответственно, следующая попытка прочитать строку кончится тем же самым исключением)

Comment: @Regent аа, точно, это же nextLine. У меня просто возникли почему то  мысли об исключениях по аналогии с nextInt. Все равно у меня и nextInt есть в коде, поэтому поменяю nextLine на nextInt.

Comment: Текущий вариант, кстати, при вводе "abc" уйдёт в бесконечный цикл с необходимостью убивать поток или всё приложение. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно добавить, например, `input.next()` в `catch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При сложной логике в теле `while` (например, несколько разных действий) вариант с флагом выглядит, на мой взгляд, оправданным. Использование do-while или while, флага успеха или неуспеха - это уже вопросы вкуса.

При простой логике с простой проверкой на допустимость значения (которая подразумевает существование недопустимых значений, одно из которых можно использовать в качестве начального) можно обойтись без флага:

```
int cellNumber = 0;
while (cellNumber < 10)
{
    try
    {
        cellNumber = input.nextInt();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException ex)
    {
        input.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Но особо короче/лучше код от этого не становится

---

Если к предыдущим условиям добавить ещё то, что действие в теле цикла всего одно и не требует оборачивания в try-catch, то его можно поместить прямо в условие цикла:

```
int cellNumber = 0;
while ((cellNumber = input.nextInt()) == 0) {}
```

(Пример для демонстрации идеи). Но условия такие встречаются нечасто, плюс, на мой взгляд, вполне справедливо кому-то не нравится такой вариант из-за того, что действие, изменяющее состояние, и проверка находятся в одной строке кода

Comment: Зачем нужен input.next? Я точно не помню, но если его не будет, то следующий ввод не пройдет?

Comment: @AntonSorokin да, при вводе не-числа (например, "abc") следующий вызов  `nextInt` будет опять пытаться обработать "abc", поэтому нужно явно сказать ему, чтобы он переходил к попытке обработать следующий токен

Comment: @AntonSorokin в коде Scanner-a есть такая строчка: `position = matcher.start(); // don't skip bad token`, а в описании метода есть такое: _"If the translation is successful, the scanner advances  past the input that matched."_

Comment: @Regent Беда в этом коде, если значение `cellNumber` может быть любым числом.

Comment: @Axenow безусловно, поэтому я уточнил _"с простой проверкой на допустимость значения"_, подразумевая под этим, что существуют недопустимые значения, на которые идёт проверка в условии, и одно из которых устанавливается в качестве начального значения

Answer (score 2):

В принципе ваш код полностью валидный, хотя я бы поменял его чутка.

```
    while(true){
        try {
            cellNumber = input.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while (true)` - на мой взгляд, крайне спорная и не наглядная конструкция

Comment: @Regent Я сам частенько использую boolean для проверок, но для маленьких циклов - я предпочитаю такой вариант, он проще читается и довольно распространен.